# Xcode 11.5/Catalina not responding on startup

Tags: xcode

I have recently upgraded both Xcode (to 11.5) and Mac OS to Catalina.  Xcode has been working fine for a few days.  I clicked on a JSON file in my project and Xcode hung (with SBBOD).  I forced quit and rebooted but now Xcode will not load - it starts, but just shows SBBOD again.  On startup, it tries to load my last project, I have tried launching from Finder by clicking on a PlayGround project but same issue!

Any suggestions for how I recover this situation?

Answer (score 0):

While the cause is not resolved, I left Xcode running overnight and it is now working.  This issue seems to be with displaying a large JSON file (about 1MB).  Xcode is taking a few hours before it becomes responsive.  I just left it to run.